# jquery different selectors that should act the same have different behaviours

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that when a td is clicked it finds the th that is directly above it and changes it's width

before I did not have a class for my td and th so I was using this selector

```
var selectedTh = $this.closest('table').find('th').eq($this.index());
```

and it worked perfectly and changed the width as it should.

Now I want to refactor it, so I have a class for the td and th (specific class for each column) - I tried using this selector

```
var selectedTh = $('th',$(this).attr('class'));
```

and when I am debugging it, I am pretty sure it is selecting the th I want
but after when I do

```
 var tableWidth = $('table').width();
                var colWidth = tableWidth / $('th', $table).length;
                selectedTh.addClass("fullWidth");
                selectedTh.animate({
                    width: colWidth + 100
                    }, 150);
```

it does nothing

Just to clarify the class I am looking for it by is not the fullwidth that I am adding it is a class that was set before and exists there.

When I was using the previous selector it was changing it correctly

Any idea how I can use the selector to choose the correct th element by class?

Comment: try this `var selectedTh = $('th','.'+$(this).attr('class'));` you are missing `.` represent of the class

Comment: It's **really** hard to help you without your HTML.

Comment: Please click the `<>` to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).attr("class")` will return the full `class` attribute of the element, which:

1. May have multiple classes in it
2. Will not have the `.` indicating it's a class selector

So no, they don't do the same thing. Moreover, the second one looks for a `th` *within* an element with the given class, which doesn't make sense if `this` is a `td`.

You're probably best off with what you have, but if you're worried about colspans or similar, if you add a common class to the `td` and `th` **and** guarantee that the `td` only has the one class, you could do:

```
var selectedTh = $this.closest('table').find('th.' + $this.attr("class"));
```

or perhaps better, add a `data-th-class` attribute to the `td` and do:

```
var selectedTh = $this.closest('table').find('th.' + $this.attr("data-th-class"));
```

...so that you can add other classes to the `td` without breaking it.

Comment: thanks, i used the second option you provided and it solved my problem